# How to send push notification after a row is inserted in parse for iOS(Obj-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-cloud-code

I have an Order table in parse. After a row is inserted in to the table, I want to send a push notification to the iOS device. How to write a cloud code for this specific task? I read parse documentation but I couldn't understand about channels, installation and other stuff related to push notifications. I have seen various blogs regarding this but I couldn't get a right answer for cloud code and how to call that code in iOS. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This question is too broad. The best suggestion that I have is going through and working through the documentation again. Also, Parse has some tutorials that you can follow that should help.

Comment: Have a look at the `afterSave` cloud code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say which devices you want to send the push notification to, so I can't provide a more specific example, but here is an `afterSave` method for a class called "Location".  In this code, a query is defined that identifies all installations that are associated with the updated location and a 'silent push' is sent to these devices -

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Location", function(request) {

  query = new Parse.Query("Installation")
  query.equalTo("location",request.object)

  Parse.Push.send({ 
      where: query,
      data: {
          "content-available" : "1",
          event: "locationUpdate"
      } 
  },{
    success:function() {
   },
   error:function() {
       console.error("Error in push "+error.code+" : "+error.message);
       }
   });

});
```

Comment: What does Location here mean? Is it the table object name in parse?

Comment: Yes, I have a "Location" class and in my "Installation" class there is a reference to the "Location" for that installation